# php - how to sync localhost mysql database stucture to webserver database without data?

Tags: php

I need to be able of sync my webserver databases , matching them with my localhost database, **but** just the structure, not the records.

Per example if I add one new table to my localhost db, I run the script and it applyes to the server db populating it with default values.

How can I do that?

replication in not what I need, since it is automatic and I don't want that.
I think the phpmyadmin synchronization would be good, but it also sync records.

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL dump with --no-data switch. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data

Comment: thanks for reply, well so many options over there :-)  I'm trying but can't find a way of making it happen, always get a 127 using this if(system("mysqldump -v --no-data -h localhost -u USER - pPASS test | mysql -h localhost -u USER -pPASS test_dump 2>&1", $system_result)) {
 echo $system_result;
}

Comment: Instead of running that in PHP, create a shell script that works and execute it from PHP (if you must). Much cleaner and less error prone approach.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I don't know how to make that shell script, need to study that. Thanks